# How can I invoke the soft-keyboard widget on Ubuntu-touch?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch

If you're building a QtQuick 2.0 app, what is the procedure for specifying that the soft-keyboard should be selectable/expandable at the bottom of the screen?

Comment: Still need to test it, but it looks like as of Qt 5 you can just "Qt.inputMethod.show()" http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtquick/qtquick-porting-qt5.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some un-styled sample code that just gets the keyboard on-screen.  The docs indicate that you need to have a text-entry selected for this to work, so if you have a custom widget, you may have to sub-class text-entry or set up a particular slot/signal.

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import Ubuntu.Components 0.1

MainView {
    // objectName for functional testing purposes (autopilot-qt5)
    objectName: "mainView"
    id: "mainview"
    applicationName: "QMLTerminal"

    width: units.gu(100)
    height: units.gu(75)
    property bool keyShowing: false
    TextEdit {
        id: textConsumer
        visible: false
        anchors.top: parent.top
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height * .10
    }

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: if (mainview.keyShowing){
                       Qt.inputMethod.hide()
                       mainview.keyShowing = false
                       textConsumer.visible = false
                       console.log("Tried to hide")
                   } else {
                       textConsumer.visible = true
                       textConsumer.focus = true
                       Qt.inputMethod.show()
                       mainview.keyShowing = true
                       console.log("Tried to show")
                   }
    }
}
```